# Optimize cython-compiled class method with scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, performance, scipy, cython

For an optimization problem, I need to find `argmin_u f(u, a)` for many, many different parameters `a`. All my code is written in Python, so I figured I would use cython to optimize this particular task. I use `scipy.optimize.minimize` for the actual optimization.

I wrote a simple cython class to wrap the function, with separate methods to set the parameter and to evaluate the function with a single input. However, when I try to optimize it, compilation works but I receive a run-time error:

```
TypeError: wrap() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

Here is a minimal example in which I managed to reproduce the error (in a `.pyx` file):

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

cdef double testfun(double x):
  return (x-3)**2

cdef class TestClass(object):
  cdef double eval(self, double x):
    return (x-5)**2

cpdef optimize_testfun():

  # this works:
  res = minimize(testfun, [0])
  print('Result: {}'.format(res.x[0]))

  # this does not work:
  cdef TestClass test_object = TestClass()
  res = minimize(test_object.eval, [0])
  print('Result: {}'.format(res.x[0]))
```

Note that for a regular compiled function, the optimization works fine. Also, for a regular Python class this construction works. I suppose the problem lies in the way that cython handles the `self` argument.

Does anyone have an idea to get the code to work with the compiled class? Or does anyone have an alternative idea of how to wrap the multi-argument function to present it as a compiled single-argument function to `minimize`?

My experience with both optimization and cython is limited, so if this is a stupid way to go about things, please let me know.

[NB. My initial question was very vaguely formulated, I almost completely rewrote it to give a clear and reproducible problem outline]

Comment: I've downvoted this because it's lacking an [mcve]. A vague outline is there but it isn't complete, and the error message does not match your simplified example.

Comment: @DavidW thanks for the feedback. a MCVE would involve at least three files, which seemed a bit over the top, given that the basic question (minimize a compiled functioneren) is pretty clear. But i will rephrase the question when I'm back home

Comment: @DavidW, I rewrote the question. You're absolutely right that I should have put more thought in this before asking - hope this is better.

Comment: Yes I realized this is way more to the point while working out the example, proving once again for myself why you should always do that :P It's definitely a duplicate, I have some questions but will ask there, then this can be closed.